# Why I can't print to any reports in Odoo?

Tags: xml, report, odoo

do you have any ideas why I can't print to any reports like from Purchase, Account, etc.?
This is the error that I get

> File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse
> (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:85131)   File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1805,
> in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:124318) TypeError:
> cannot parse from 'bool' load could not load template Template: 259

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it. I just uninstall the custom modules and upgraded the `report` module then reinstall the the custom modules again.